How can I monitor application performance?
I've encountered an issue where I'm not sure which direction to take. My application is using GCP. I want to monitor the performance, mostly in requests, not infrastructure, as far as i've looked I can monitor backend performance with google cloud trace(correct me if i'm wrong).
For the frontend it's a bit tricky, I'm not really sure how I can measure the duration a page takes to fully load and send the value somewhere I can exploit it. The idea is to save all the metrics and print them in dashboards and trigger alerting etc.. (preferably on gcp but not closed to other tools).
Any idea/track would be appreciated, thanks !

What are you actually using in GCP? More detail is needed to even start thinking about an answer

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Please specify your question a bit more as it is quite general.
But to give you more information, you can use Cloud Monitoring(https://cloud.google.com/monitoring) with Cloud Logging(https://cloud.google.com/logging) and create custom metrics that capture what you see necessary through the logs and then display it in custom dashboards in Monitoring.
I hope this helps.
